# Received invalid Windows system error code

Tags: windows, system-error

In my C++ Windows application I received what appears to be an invalid system error code using GetLastError() after a failed Overlapped I/O operation.

```
// Code
DWORD errorCode = GetLastError();
loggerInt1(LOGERROR, "failed getIoResult, errorCode %d", (int)errorCode);

// Log file
failed getIoResult, errorCode -1073741781
failed getIoResult, errorCode -1073741781
failed getIoResult, errorCode -1073741781
//... many more times at different time points
```

errorCode is a DWORD, which is an unsigned long, and I casted it to int.  But Windows system error codes should only be between 0 and 15999, well within an int.

-1073741781 is C000 002B on 32-bit system (mine) and FFFF FFFF C000 002B on 64-bit system.  Interpreted as unsigned long it's 3,221,225,515 (32-bit) or some freakishly huge number (64-bit).  Either way it's well outside of the 0-15999 range of a Windows system error.

How can this be?  Is there a sane reason for why I got such an error code?

Comment: What is the API that failed? Remember, the value returned by `GetLastError` is undefined if the previous API call did not fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0xC000002B is an [NTSTATUS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704588.aspx) code which resolves to `STATUS_PARITY_ERROR`.

There is no contractual agreement that a value stored here is a standard Win32 error code. The documentation for `GetLastError` vaguely implies this:

> The error codes returned by a function are not part of the Windows API
>   specification and can vary by operating system or device driver. For this reason, we cannot provide the complete list of error codes that can be returned by each function

The standard error codes are well documented, so the above statement wouldn't make much sense if all possible results are initially understood.

Note that some WINAPIs can also return HRESULT values.

Comment: I do know that user app can do SetLastError(), but definitely not my code.  So it must come from the OS or the driver code.  Any idea on how such an error comes from the GetOverlappedResult() system call? I would like to isolate the problem to either the OS or the driver.  Thanks.

Comment: Considering that it is a parity error, it is likely coming from the driver which is talking to the hardware device in question.